# How to make JHipster use Javascript instead of Typescript for React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jhipster

I would need JHipster to use Javascript and create js Files for React project instead of Typescript, for which tsx files are generated, because I have bought a React template which contains Javascript only and which I want to include into the JHipster project.

Before trying to convert to Typescript, I received the following error for every file:

```
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
```

After trying to convert my template to Typescript, but I am receiving many errors and I would like to avoid losing many days trying to convert this.

Is it possible to use only Javascript in the React project generated by JHipster?

Or does anybody have a solution for this?

Comment: JHipster cannot be configured to generate javascript but nothing prevents you from having a project using both languages, see https://medium.com/swlh/convert-your-javascript-react-app-to-typescript-the-easy-guide-631592dc1876 You need to configure webpack, no need to modify your source files.